# Build-it ListView is transparent - how to set opaque?

Tags: android, user-interface, layout, android-listview

I have following simple lines of piece that build up a list view for me:

```
ffLv = new ListView(this); // create my ListView
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1);
for (int i=0; i<ffList.size(); i++)
{
   ... // fill the adapter with data here
}
ffLv.setAdapter(adapter);
rootLayout.addView(ffLv);
```

"rootLayout" is a FrameLayout where the ListView shall stay on top and cover all the other elements in this view. Amazingly the ListView is transparent, the lines between the items and the text in each item is drawn on top of the other contents.

How can I change that to have an opaque ListView? Do I really have to add a Panel as parent of the ListView or is there a more simple way to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the background color on any element with `setBackgroundColor()`, for instance:

```
ffLv.setBackgroundColor(0x55ffffff).
```